# Seconds from epoch to datetime conversion is returning GMT c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# function that expects a seconds from epoch argument in microseconds generated from a python publisher:

```
buffer.setTimestamp(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())*1000*1000)
```

The c# function:

```
public static DateTime datetimeFromEpochTime(ulong timestamp)
{
     DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
     DateTime ts = epoch.AddMilliseconds(timestamp / 1000);
     TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
     return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(ts, cstZone);
}
```

The returned timestamp however seems to be 5 hours ahead (I'm in CST). For example if I enter `1438004994000000`, the timestamp becomes `7/27/2015 1:49:54 PM` though it should be `7/27/2015 8:49:54 AM`

Comment: [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is `UTC`. That's why your first line should be `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.UTC)` After you do that, you can call `ToLocalTime` in your second line. Your timestamp is equal to `Mon, 27 Jul 2015 13:49:54 GMT`.

Comment: I'm getting back the time you expect from the sample code.

Comment: Changing it to `DateTimeKind.Utc` produces the right output. Thanks.